# Norm bound for the Jordan basis matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, jordan-normal-form

Suppose I have a matrix $A$. We can assume, if it will be relevant, that it is stochastic with entries in $\{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},1\}$ and eigenvalues with magnitudes in $(0,1]$.

$A$ has a Jordan decomposition $A = VJV^{-1}$. I would like to find an upper bound  $\|V\|_{2}$ and $\|V^{-1}\|_{2}$.

I know that I can take $V$ to be a generalized eigenvector basis, so a crude bound for $\|V\|_{F}$ can be $n^{2}$, implying $\|V\|_{2} \le n^{3}$. If so, what about $\| V^{-1} \|$? Any bound (w.r.t. $n$) will be useful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure about the stochastic matrices with these entries, but generally $\|V\|\|V^{-1}\|$ does not need to have a useful upper bound. Consider, e.g., $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\\epsilon&1}$, for which $\|V\|\|V^{-1}\|\rightarrow+\infty$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ (this actually might happen for any sequence of diagonalizable matrices with a non-diagonalizable limit).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. In this example, the bound is $O(\epsilon^{-1})$. Bounds such as this, although generally not useful, are indeed useful in my case (where even something that is exponential in $n$, or in the minimal entry, will do).